# pgfplots: Two Y-axes plot

Tags: pgfplots, floats, pgfplotstable, plot

Suppose I have the following data for five different categories:
[image]

I would like to create a figure showing the mean (and the 1-std.-band around the return) in something like the graph below (mean and std in y-axis, the different categories x-axis). Would it also be possible to add the Sharpe as a red/orange triangle in the same graph (with a secondary y-axis on right)?

[image]

Comment: It is much more convenient and easier to use gnuplot for the task (I have done it for several years =), then export the image into ```.png``` or ```.pdf```  and just put it into your document, If only You do not have task to do it using only LaTeX...

Comment: How would this work in gnuplot? I have downloaded the program, but it feels a bit difficult to use.

Comment: Something like that? http://gnuplot.info/demo_svg_5.2/errorbars.html